# Is there any limits of saving result on S3 from sagemaker Processing?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

※ I used google translation, if you have any question, let me know!

I am trying to run python script with huge 4 data, using sagemaker processing. And my current situation are as follows:

- can run this script with 3 data
- can't run the script with only 1 data (the biggest, the same structure with others)
- as for all of 4 data, the script has finished (so, I suspected this error in S3, ie. when copying sagemaker result to S3)

The error I got is this InternalServerError.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sagemaker_train_and_predict.py", line 56, in <module>
    outputs=outputs
  File "{xxx}/sagemaker_constructor.py", line 39, in run
    outputs=outputs
  File "{masked}/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/processing.py", line 408, in run
    self.latest_job.wait(logs=logs)
  File "{masked}/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/processing.py", line 723, in wait
    self.sagemaker_session.logs_for_processing_job(self.job_name, wait=True)
  File "{masked}/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py", line 3111, in logs_for_processing_job
    self._check_job_status(job_name, description, "ProcessingJobStatus")
  File "{masked}/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py", line 2615, in _check_job_status
    actual_status=status,
sagemaker.exceptions.UnexpectedStatusException: Error for Processing job sagemaker-vm-train-and-predict-2020-04-12-04-15-40-655: Failed. Reason: InternalServerError: We encountered an internal error.  Please try again.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be some issue transferring the output data to S3 if the output is generated at a high rate and size is too large.

You can 1) try to slow down writing the output a bit or 2) call S3 from your algorithm container to upload the output directly using boto client (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html).